# Do Mortys have extra defense against their own type?

Tags: pocket-mortys

If I'm fighting a Scruffy Morty, who is a rock type, it would be best to use a paper type Morty, such as Ad Morty or Blue Shirt Morty. If I'm all out of paper types, or don't have any, would it be better to use a rock type, or a plain type? Assuming level and health/attack points are all the same.

I guess my real question is, do Mortys have extra defense against their own type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No** - the Pokemon analogy holds up here too. Rock type Mortys receive 1x damage from rock types, more damage from paper types, and reduced damage from scissors types, etc.